# Want to open an inbound HTTP other than port # 80 on my AWS medium instance

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, amazon-ec2, http

I have been able to open port 80 for inbound HTTP traffic on my medium AWS instance running Windows 2008 R2 with IIS 7.5

I want to be able to open another port (say 8000) for inbound HTTP traffic. I'm unable to find a way to do so (at least from the AWS console)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your VPC under Security Groups, select the Security Group assigned to your server and go to Inbound rules.

From there, select Custom TCP rule and type in the port you want to open (8000) into the Port Range box.

In source, either put 0.0.0.0/0 for all traffic or a specific ip range.